# Dynamically generate dropdown list from <html:options>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, taglib

I have a piece of code block like the following:

```
    <html:select size="1" property="organizationPrimaryKey" styleClass="inputField" >
       <option value=""></option>
       <html:options collection="organizationsList" property="primaryKey" 
       labelProperty="qualifiedName"/>
    </html:select>
```

Now I want to add some style guide which is recommended by our company, so modified the code like this:

```
<div class="esg-dropdown" id="esg-dropdown" onClick="toggleCssClass()">
                            <button class="esg-button esg-button--secondary esg-dropdown__toggle" id="dropdownMenuDefault" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Dropdown <span class="esg-dropdown__icon esg-dropdown__icon--right esg-icon__container" aria-hidden="True">
                            <svg class="esg-icon esg-icon--small esg-icon--light esg-icon--up">
                                <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-arrow"></use>
                            </svg></span></button>
                          <ul class="esg-dropdown__menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuDefault">
                            <li class="esg-dropdown__menu-item"><a class="esg-dropdown__link"> Root</a></li>
                            <li class="esg-dropdown__menu-item"><a class="esg-dropdown__link"> Sub Root</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
```

But I am unable to generate the values dynamically, as previous structure was using the jsp taglib.

> Is there any way of populating the values dynamically which satisfy
>
> ```
> <html:options collection="organizationsList" property="primaryKey"labelProperty="qualifiedName"/>
> ```

I am trying to get all the values from the  in an  array during run time:

```
var optionValues = [];
alert(optionValues);
$('#state option').each(function() {
    optionValues.push($(this).val());
    alert(optionValues);
});

<html:select size="1" property="organizationPrimaryKey" styleClass="inputField" styleId="state">

                            <html:options collection="organizationsList" property="primaryKey" labelProperty="qualifiedName"/>
                            </html:select>
```

but each tine it is getting only null values

Comment: Well yes, Since you have removed all the ids it will probably not bind the data to your new drop down. From where you binding values to the drop down?

Comment: Hi @imanshu15. It was rendering properly with jsp taglib with old block of code. but as I mentioned i need to apply some style for that i have made am using button and <li> for dynamic dropdownlist. so my question is how to load the same data to the new dropdown list which is there in <html:select> ?